# Can I checkout & commit to several Mercurial hg branches at once?

Tags: mercurial, merge, commit, branching-and-merging

I've forked a project from the internet, and I want to write some new features. I want to write several orthogonal features at the same time, (eg. debug helpers, new feature X, new feature Y), and have the code for all of them in my current directory, but when I commit, I want to be able to say "these files go to branch 'debug'", "those files go to branch 'feature X'", etc. Where these are branches in the 'hg branches' sense.

The reason for this is the project upstream may not want to merge my debug helpers or hacked bug fixes, but I certainly want to use them whilst developing my features.

Effectively, I just want to apply the changes in those files to the branch, but keep several branches checked out & merged to my current working directory.

Is this possible? Perhaps there's some hg extension to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [mercurial queues (MQ)](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial) for things like debug helpers or local hacks. Very useful for patches that you only want locally and may want to apply to any revision/branch.

Doing the same thing with branches becomes tedious IMHO as you have to be very careful to do the changes for debug and features on different branches, and then merge them in to a local, throwaway branch in order to run anything. You can end up with lots of changesets on the feature branch that leave the tree in a broken state because you can only test after you commit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you'd you would want to do things that way. If your features are orthogonal, you can work on them independently until they are ready to be merged. That is exactly what branches are for after all!

But to answer your question: you could `commit` on a branch and then, as a matter of workflow, always `up` to default and `merge` it in. That would keep the default branch as the sum of the other features. You would need to `update` to the feature branch before you commit, though and that could get tedious.

The other option for *post-facto* determining which branch you want to commit to is to use the [`rebase`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) extension. In this case, you'd commit your changes and then do `hg rebase -d targetBranch`.

I don't recommend using history revisions as part of your standard workflow, though. That smells to me.